# JHipster microservice app throws invalid JWT error

Tags: jwt, jhipster, keycloak

I am attempting to connect to a JHipster generated microservice application using JWT authentication. I have verified my token and public key on jwt.io, but when I plug in my public key to my service's *base64-secret* parameter in application-XXX.yml I receive the following:

```
inventory-app_1    | 2020-09-02 17:40:07.351  INFO 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] xxxx.security.jwt.TokenProvider  : Invalid JWT token.
inventory-app_1    | 2020-09-02 17:40:07.384  WARN 1 --- [  XNIO-1 task-1] o.z.problem.spring.common.AdviceTraits   : Unauthorized: Full authentication is required to access this resource
```

My token/key are generated by a Keycloak v7.0 server using RS256. I am using the public key found at *https://myUrl.com/auth/realms/realmName/protocol/openid-connect/certs*, key value x5c

If my JWT/key pair is already known to be valid - what factors can stop my JHipster/spring server from recognizing the token?

**Edit:* I was able to extract the following error message:*

```
The parsed JWT indicates it was signed with the RS256 signature algorithm, but the specified signing key of type j
avax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec may not be used to validate RS256 signatures.  Because the specified signing key reflects a specific and expected algorithm, and the JWT does not reflect this algorithm, it is likely that the JWT was n
ot expected and therefore should not be trusted.  Another possibility is that the parser was configured with the incorrect signing key, but this cannot be assumed for security reasons.
```

To me this error seems to suggest that it is not possible to use RS256 signed tokens, but it is not fully clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JHipster generated JWT security only allows for HMAC signing